# How to remove ajax part of a form

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

I have got a template from bootstrap website and trying to customize it.
In the contact page,I didn't get the submit action PHP file as it is only available for paid version.

So, I linked it with google forms by customizing the same form.
Now, the form is being submitted and able to collect the details but as the submit is showing it as error message in the same page.

[image]

If I remove the attribute **class="php-email-form"** in the form, the ajax part is gone and I am able to submit the form and no error messages as it is opening the google form submission success page.
But all the staying and form validations are also lost.I didn't find any linkage in the js file also for this class.

Source code: Free version in the [link](https://bootstrapmade.com/mentor-free-education-bootstrap-theme/)

When I checked, the below is the validate.js responsible for this.
But, I want to keep all the validations except, the form submission should open the target page instead of showing the status here.If possible, showing the same page but with success message for google forms.

```
    /**
* PHP Email Form Validation - v2.0
* URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/php-email-form/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
*/
!(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $('form.php-email-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs
     
      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (! i.is(':checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;

    var this_form = $(this);
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    if( ! action ) {
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html('The form action property is not set!');
      return false;
    }
    
    this_form.find('.sent-message').slideUp();
    this_form.find('.error-message').slideUp();
    this_form.find('.loading').slideDown();

    if ( $(this).data('recaptcha-site-key') ) {
      var recaptcha_site_key = $(this).data('recaptcha-site-key');
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha_site_key, {action: 'php_email_form_submit'}).then(function(token) {
          php_email_form_submit(this_form,action,this_form.serialize() + '&recaptcha-response=' + token);
        });
      });
    } else {
      php_email_form_submit(this_form,action,this_form.serialize());
    }
    
    return true;
  });

  function php_email_form_submit(this_form, action, data) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: data,
      timeout: 40000
    }).done( function(msg){
      if (msg == 'OK') {
        this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
        this_form.find('.sent-message').slideDown();
        this_form.find("input:not(input[type=submit]), textarea").val('');
      } else {
        this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
        if(!msg) {
          msg = 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action + '<br>';
        }
        this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(msg);
      }
    }).fail( function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var error_msg = "Form submission failed!<br>";
      if(data.statusText || data.status) {
        error_msg += 'Status:';
        if(data.statusText) {
          error_msg += ' ' + data.statusText;
        }
        if(data.status) {
          error_msg += ' ' + data.status;
        }
        error_msg += '<br>';
      }
      if(data.responseText) {
        error_msg += data.responseText;
      }
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(error_msg);
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```